# Converting time variable into a numeric value in SAS

Tags: variables, sas, datetime-format

I've done a substracting of time variables (sleeptime = waketime - bedtime) and, although I get the correct result I need to categorize the sleeptime into 2 categories (sleep =0 if sleeptime => 7hours or sleep=1 if < than 7h).

The problem is that when I categorize the variable, I don't get the classification right. This is what I get:

```
bedtime   waketime   sleeptime sleep
22:00:00  07:00:00   09:00:00  1
22:30:00  06:30:00   08:00:00  1
00:55:00  08:10:00   07:15:00  0
02:30:00  08:30:00   06:00:00  1
```

Here's the code I've used:

```
data have;  set want;
sleeptime = waketime - bedtime;
if sleeptime => '07:00:00't then sleep=0;
if sleeptime < '07:00:00't then sleep=1; run;
```

I've been think into converting the sleeptime into a value so that it's easier to categorize, for example:

```
bedtime   waketime   sleeptime sleeptime1
22:00:00  07:00:00   09:00:00  9
22:30:00  06:30:00   08:00:00  8
02:30:00  08:30:00   06:00:00  6
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your sleeptime in the table above is not correct based on the data you have, you need to account for crossing days. Do you have a date component to those times?

Comment: Sadly, I don't. but the solution provided by Joe works.

Comment: Yeah, it'll work in 99.9% of use cases except ones where someone sleeps 24 hours or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time variables are numeric, so you're fine leaving it alone... but you're forgetting about midnight!

Either keep your variables as `datetime` (which keeps the date, so it lets you do this sort of thing just as you did it), or fudge it:

```
data have;
input bedtime :time8.  waketime :time8.;
datalines;
22:00:00  07:00:00   
22:30:00  06:30:00   
00:55:00  08:10:00   
02:30:00  08:30:00   
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  sleeptime = waketime-bedtime + (86400*(bedtime gt waketime));
  format bedtime waketime sleeptime time8.;
run;
```

This only works if you're sure it's always going to be true that `waketime` should be after `bedtime`.  Seems likely, but worth pointing out.  (And, 86400 is the number of seconds in 24 hours - you can also use `'24:00:00't` if you want.)

Comment: Thanks! Now it's categorizing completely fine!!